# A windows container cannot be stopped succesfully

Tags: docker, containers, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I use the dotnet3.5 image to run containers on win10 with docker desktop 2.1.0.1(37199). Sadly, I found that after I had created a container, did nothing to it, and left it alone for 4 days, the container automotically became unstoppable. The snapshot tells the story.[image]

The container seemed existing there when ***docker ps -a***, but I cannot get into the container by ***docker exec***. And for I cannot stop it--the docker stop process hangs there after I use ***docker stop container2***--I cannot rm the container.

The only way to resolve this issue is to restore docker desktop's factory setting.

By the way, although in the snapshot the running image is aspnet:3.5-windowsservercore-10.0.14393.953, this issue also happens when the aspnet:3.5

Does anyone have good ideas to the unstoppable container? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

The command used above is incorrect. There is a difference between the commands and options we use. "# docker ps" or "# docker container ls" will give you the list of currently running processes or active containers.

Whereas "-a" will give you all the list of all those which are used to date which contains the list of active and deleted containers.

In your case, the container was is not there and you are trying to access the one which is non-existing, which is why it is stuck.